# readfile() method prints file instead of downloading

Tags: php

I want to download a file using PHP from an absolute path using the header() and readfile() methods. It used to work before, but doesn't anymore.

I've tried changing the Content-type, but nothing worked.

```php
$p = $_GET['plugin'];
$v = $_GET['version'];
if (isset($p) && isset($v)) {
    if (in_array($p, getPlugins($_SESSION['username']))) {
        $url = '/home/uploads/' . $p . '/' . $v . '.jar';
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: application/java-archive");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $p . ' ' . $v . '.jar"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize($url));
        readfile($url);
        //header('Location: plugins.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

It should download the jar file that should be named something like "MyPlugin Snapshot-1.0.0.jar". Instead, it prints the whole jar file to the page (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following content type:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```

Did that do the trick?

Comment: Yeh did that. Didn't change anything. It's still being printed on the page instead of downloading